# Why is the rectangle not shown when I used drawRect()?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-canvas

Why is the rectangle not shown when I used drawRect() on canvas object,
and also declared it inside onCreate method.

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
    Chronometer stopWatch = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chrono);
    mDrawingActivity = (DrawingActivity)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    b.setText("start");
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**OnDraw() Method**

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas Square) 
    {
        super.onDraw(Square);
            Paint squareColor = new Paint();
            squareColor.setColor(Color.CYAN); // change the box color to cyan
        Square.drawRect(100,100,100,100, squareColor); 
return;
    }
```

Clarification: Even the button and chronometer are not shown too and the program is forced closed.

Comment: Please, provide also code in which you are drawing rect

Comment: Just read in the doc what the parameters `right` and `bottom` of `Canvas.drawRect()` mean

Answer (score 7):

You are drawing an point rectangle. 
Change line

```
Square.drawRect(100,100,100,100, squareColor);
```

to

```
Square.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, squareColor)
```

Here is the definition from doc.

```
drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

Draw the specified Rect using the specified paint. The rectangle will be filled or framed based on the Style in the paint.

Parameters
left    The left side of the rectangle to be drawn
top The top side of the rectangle to be drawn
right   The right side of the rectangle to be drawn
bottom  The bottom side of the rectangle to be drawn
paint   The paint used to draw the rect